# Using async as with condition in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use async as pipe to get the value of the status of my code.

```
<ng-container
        *ngIf="
            ((loaded$ | async) ||
                ((status$ | async) as status ==='Started'))
            else load
        "
    >
```

'Async as' doesn't seem to work with a condition. Following code works fine for me, but it looks a bit messed up:

```
 <ng-container
            *ngIf="
                ((loaded$ | async) ||
                    ((status$ | async) === 'Started')) && (status$ | async) as status;
                else load
            "
        >
```

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add more expression for `if` after `as`.

I think you can add a simple `getter` for that?

```js
get startedStatus$() {
   return this.status$.pipe(
      map(status => status === 'Started' && status)
   );
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(loaded$ | async) || (startedStatus$ | async as status); else load">
```